# How to process the payment in woocommerce using ajax in plugins?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building custom payment gateway which will load the credit card form in iframe and credit card details will be handled by their server from my site i am submitting the billinginfo details once i submitted i will get the status as 'Approved' and transaction id. The response will be handled in javascript event. Please guide me to process the payment once i got the response from their server.

Once i got the response from their server i am trying to pass those reponse using ajaxurl through the function defined in the plugin. i am getting 400 bad request. Please check with my code

**Custom Gateway plugin**

```
 <?
  class WC_Custom_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
    public function __construct() {
//Defined all the required fields
  add_action('wp_ajax_get_process_payment', array(     $this,'get_process_payment'));      
     add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_process_payment',array( $this,'get_process_payment') );
    } 
public function init_form_fields(){ 
  //Defined necessary fields
 }
public function payment_fields() {
 echo '<input id="token" name="token" type="hidden" value="sadfasdf'" />'; 
  //Iframe load cc form ?>
<script src="customgatway_script.js"></script>
<script>
var success = function(response){
//This is the where the response i am getting
 jQuery.ajax({
                 type : "POST",                                          

                url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',                  
                //data: response,
                data: {action:'get_process_payment'},
                dataType : "json",
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(response) { 
 }
};
 var decline = function(response){
 };
 var error = function(response){
 }
jQuery("form.woocommerce-checkout").on('submit', function () {
 submitbillinginfo(checkouttoken,billingfirst_name,etc)
}
</script>
<?php
   }
 function get_process_payment(){
   Process Payment
  }
   //or call the native function of woocommerce      process_payment($order_id)



 }
```

Comment: I think calling the wp_ajax action inside of the Gateway is too late for the action to take affect.  You should call it outside of the gateway class.  Unfortunately, this is the only way I believe.  It would be nice if there was a class method or hook of some sort to add a wp_ajax action into a gateway, but I don't see anyway to do it.